# FK on users table vs new table users_role

Tags: mysql, relational-database

This question had been probably answered in other posts but I've been searching and I didn't find something similar (quite funny):

I work with laravel 5.7. I'm just a beginner on this framework.

I've a users table and I want to add role to the users. At first, my idea was simply create a new table "roles" and add a FK to users table (role_id), but after googling in some pages, I found that sometimes pleople create a new table role_user for that purpose.

My doubt is:

- Which method is better or more correct and why?
  My question is not only about the correct way but also about performance and any other reason I still don't know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a many-to-many relationship between users and roles. You need to use the intermediate user_role table to resolve that relationship.

[image]